# move the marker to selected location on MapContainer

Tags: codenameone

In my application, user can select a location on map and save its latlong. I'm using Mapcontainer to display map. When user selects a location, a marker should be displayed and if another location is selected then the marker should be moved to that location. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using map `addTapListener()`, see below code:

```
final MapContainer map = new MapContainer();
map.addTapListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        map.clearMapLayers();
        map.addMarker(encImageMarkerIcon, new Coord(map.getCoordAtPosition(evt.getX(), evt.getY())), "", "", (evt1) -> {
            //whatever you want the marker to do when touched
        });
        form.revalidate();
    }
});
```